# Extract NCT id from ClinicalTrials.gov using python

Tags: python

I found online some functions able to extract different features from articles taken from ClinicalTrials.gov. The problem is that these functions require in input the NCT id of the article and I am not able to create a function with a list of NCT. I tried to use Beautiful Soup in order to download the xml of the ClinicalTrials.gov page but I want to extract a list of NCT.
This is my code:

```
url = ['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=atrial+fibrillation&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=']

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('ct2/show/NCT'))
```

The function soup.find_all does not find anything.
What's the problem?

Comment: That page doesn't contain `ct2/show`.

Answer (score 0):

The response.content returns bytes, but response.text returns string!
Use response.text instead of response.content.
Like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I think the re.compile function is wrong because the 'ct2/show/NCT' is not present in the html but I want to obtain the NCT